# Cocoa : Hide any window using accessibility

Tags: macos, cocoa, accessibility

I am wondering how to hide/show any window (not belonging to my application) using accessibility.
It should be Mac App Store compliant (I already have a version using private function, but this is something I would like  to stop).

Thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: What is the private function to hide the window? Looking to do something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that to a window using Accessibility. You can set the AXHidden of an AXApplication, or the AXMinimized of an AXWindow, but you can't simply hide (set AXHidden of) an AXWindow.